# Java: to use URLDecoder but reserve the plus sign(+)

Tags: java, lucene

I'm writing a lucene server. I want to receive the post query like :
**http://www.site.com/search?+title:google +type:website**

but the post argument **"+title:google +type:website"** is encoded like this: **"+title:google%20+type:website"**
so I use URLDecoder.decode(argument,"UTF-8") to get the original input, but I get the wrong result:

**" title:goole type:website"**, because the URLDecoder convert the plus sign "+" into a space character " ". What can I do to get the decode argument without converting plus sign?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually All spaces will be replaced by %20 , so u can replace all the %20 to space once you get the URL string.

Comment: but i need to handle Chinese, the Chinese character is encoded as well

Comment: But its the matter of space . not related to any specific character, if chinese do provide an example

Comment: I just fixed this problem by re-writing URLDecode.decode() function. thank you any way

Answer (score 7):

You can try this:

"+title:google%20+type:website".replaceAll("\\+", "%2b")

It will replace all plus signs and after that you use the decoder, which will convert back the plus sign